# Using the Subcaption package changes caption font

Tags: fonts, subcaption

I'm using the [SIGCHI conference paper template](https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/tree/master/LaTeX), and having an issue with the `subcaption` package. When I don't include it, the template makes the figure captions look like this (the way they are supposed to):

[image]

But when I include it, the captions look like this (even if it's just a regular figure, not a subfigure):

[image]

I cannot figure out how to make the captions with the `subcaption` package look like they're supposed to for the template. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[chi_draft]{sigchi}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/sigchi-logo.png}
        \caption{test}
    \end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions for how to force the caption font to the one specified by the template?

Comment: The `subcaption` package loads the `caption` package which overwrites the available mechanism with it's own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks fairly close.

[image]

```
\documentclass[chi_draft]{sigchi}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={bf,small},skip=0.6\baselineskip, labelsep=period}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{test}
        \label{fig:gps}
    \end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the suggestion, I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You get this warning:

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

It simply means that you should *not* use `caption` or packages based upon it (such as `subcaption`) with the `sigchi` document class.

You can use `subfig`, if you need subfigures.

```
\documentclass[chi_draft]{sigchi}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
\subfloat[Subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer, tnx dude!